# Why does the iframe in a webpage doesn't load using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

A website has two iframes in it. When I manually open the website, both the frames display content. But when I open the website using Selenium WebDriver + Java, the first frame doesn't load while the second frame loads. I tried using explicit wait with expected conditions of element visibility. I also tried refreshing the webpage & clearing the cache and cookies of the web browser.

Comment: some times, the frame loads when we do any action like mouse over, focus. try to do the mouse over on the frame1. it may loads.

Comment: check the iframe source is cross domain and Secure ?

Comment: what code have you tried so far show us , then only we can suggest.